# REGEX: How to parse a variable number of datapoints each inside the same prefixed text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this source data

```
[gallery]
Title
[galleryitem]http://www.google.com/image.jpg[/galleryitem]
[galleryitem]http://www.google.com/image.jpg[/galleryitem]
[galleryitem]http://www.google.com/image.jpg[/galleryitem]
[galleryitem]http://www.google.com/image.jpg[/galleryitem]
[galleryitem]http://www.google.com/image.jpg[/galleryitem]
[galleryitem]http://www.google.com/image.jpg[/galleryitem]
[/gallery]
```

Now the way this works is that this is a gallery box which starts with a title for the gallery box followed by a series of [galleryitem] tags that encapsulate an image URL.

The issues is that there is going to be a variable # of these galleryitem images, so I can't figure out a way to handle this via regex.

What I would ideally do is match all the images into some kind of an array that I could loop through and deal with on an individual basis.  THis is all being done within Javascript BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the matches one at a time. Here's the pattern I usually use:

```
var bbcode = "...";
var pattern = /\[galleryitem\]([^\[]*)\[\/galleryitem\]/g;
var match, url;

while (match = pattern.exec(bbcode)) {
    url = match[1];
    // do something with url
}
```

How does this work? The RegExp object (`pattern`) keeps track of its current index in the string, and each time you call `exec`, it searches for the next match starting at the stored index. When there are no matches left, `exec` returns null and the loop is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to call `RegExp.exec()` repeatedly.

```
function getGalleryItems(str) {
  var matches    = [],
    galleryitems = [],
    re           = /\[galleryitem\]([^\[]*)\[\/galleryitem]/g;
  while (matches !== null) {
    matches = re.exec(str);
    if (matches !=== null) {
      galleryitems.push(matches[1]);
    }
  }
  return galleryitems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still (clearly...) new to regex, but here's what I came up with:

```
var text = "[gallery]Title[galleryitem]http://www.google.com/image.jpg[/galleryitem][galleryitem]http://www.google.com/image.jpg[/galleryitem][galleryitem]http://www.google.com/image.jpg[/galleryitem][galleryitem]http://www.google.com/image.jpg[/galleryitem][galleryitem]http://www.google.com/image.jpg[/galleryitem][galleryitem]http://www.google.com/image.jpg[/galleryitem][/gallery]"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;

​var parsedText = text.replace(/(\[\/*galleryitem\])|(\[\/*gallery\])|title/gi,' ').split(/\s+/);

var imgs = [];
for (var i=0,len=parsedText.length;i<len;i++){
    if (parsedText[i] != ''){
        imgs.push(parsedText[i]);
    }
}

console.log(imgs);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fhPWv/).

While I do hope it's useful, in some manner, I'm also hoping that someone might stop by and, after laughing for a little while, might tell me how I could/should simplify that monstrosity...